# drawing within Controls in C++

Tags: c++

How to draw shapes in Form or in Panel or other control in Visual Studion 2010? I learned draw in main window: just write code in WM_PAINT section using hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps). But how to do it within form, what hWnd must i use?

Answer (score 1):

You need subclass the control and override the handler of WM_PAINT. And create the subclassed control.

This might be helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/480/Create-your-own-controls-the-art-of-subclassing